# changing ggplot + geom_sf choropleth fill colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

This concerns the `ggplot2` version on github, which supports plotting spatial data from the `sf` package. It is installed by

```
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")
```

I had expected the following

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2) 
nc <- read_sf(system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package="sf"))
ggplot() + geom_sf(data = nc) + aes(fill = BIR74) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(color = "white")) +
  scale_colour_gradientn(colors = terrain.colors(20))
```

to give terrain colors, however it gives

[image]

How do I manipulate the fill colors?

Comment: use `scale_fill_gradientn()` instead